# INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT when installing on particular device

Tags: android, dex, android-install-apk

When attempting to install an app on my Sony Xperia Z3 using `adb`, I get the following output:

```
3090 KB/s (2508014 bytes in 0.792s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/MyApp_release.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT]
```

I have previously installed exactly the same APK file on the device successfully several weeks ago, although I seem to recall there was a firmware update on the phone since I last successfully installed.

I can also install this same APK on my Motorola Moto G.

If I look at the `logcat` output while I'm installing, I see:

```
I/PackageManager( 2084): Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl-125738692
I/PackageManager( 2084): Running dexopt on: com.xxx.yyy.app
E/installd( 1635): installd cannot open '/data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.xxx.yyy.app-1.apk@classes.dex' for output during dexopt
W/PackageManager( 2084): Couldn't delete native library directory /data/app-lib/com.xxx.yyy.app
W/PackageManager( 2084): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.xxx.yyy.app-1.apk
```

This suggests that something has screwed up at some point causing some of the files that need to be written to during installation not to be writable by the installer. The list of installed apps doesn't show an existing version of the app as being installed (and I've tried an adb uninstall anyway). Unfortunately I'm not able to delete the files using `rm` on my device which isn't rooted.

After seeing this, I decided to rename the package and rebuild the APK and I'm then able to successfully install.

In the long term, I don't really want to rename the package (I only tried it as a temporary workaround to see if the package name was the issue). I don't want to root my phone (which I'm sure would allow me to then clean up whatever mess has been left behind), and I don't really want to do a factory reset (which I'm sure would also fix it). Does anyone have any other suggestions I've overlooked?

Comment: You might try using "run-as" to run a command as the deleted app, and try to remove the native library directory. I'm not sure if that will work with "partially deleted" packages like that. I can't really think of anything else you could try though, other than a factory reset, as you mentioned.

Comment: Also, great question :)

Comment: @JesusFreke - Thanks, great suggestion and something I hadn't thought of trying, but sadly as you suspected it doesn't work on this partially deleted package - I get `run-as: Package 'com.xxx.yyy.app' is unknown`